# IndexedDB transaction commit after handling error

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have been trying to put 2,5 million randomly generated people in the database.
In the code i made a batch of 2.500 users and then commit the transaction.

the chancejs library generates a guid, but is not always unique. So whenever it is not unique, i want it to put the error in an array and ignore the .add & commit the transaction anyway.

```
var transaction = db.connection.transaction(["users"], "readwrite"); 
var request = objectStore.add(newuser);

for (i=0;i<batchsize;i++){
  request.onerror = function(event) {
   event.cancelBubble = true;
   // Some kind of CONTINUE event here
  }
}
```

The transactions work and I can fill my database with all the users.
putting the createIndex 'bsn' on unique makes it fail though.

```
var index = objectStore.createIndex("bsn", "bsn", { unique: true });
```

Comment: event.cancelBubble is deprecated, and might fail in future browsers. You should use event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a request fail, the default action of the event is aborting its rransaction. If you don't want that behavior,  call event.preventDefault() on onerror handler of request or transaction.

Comment: I will test this tommorow i've tried putting it on preventDefault = true, but i didn't know you should call the function. Thanks a bunch for this reply.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the transaction from aborting, but the event will still propagate to the transaction.onerror handler, something that might be confusing. If you want to get rid of that message, simply call `event.stopPropagation()`. More info and example code can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22836716/200987).

Comment: No `event.stopPropagation()` is not necessary. Propagation of the event is fine, so that you can receive it in `tx.onerror` callback. BTW, tx will continue to run even after `tx.onerror` call. Finally it suppose to bubble up the event to `window.onerror` callback.

Comment: NOTE: propagation to the transaction.onerror handler does not abort the transaction.