# Prevent IndexedDB request error from cancelling the transaction

Tags: javascript, html, transactions, indexeddb

**My intent**

Loop through localStorage and put the data into IndexedDB.
If certain known errors happen, such as a ConstraintError when a key already exists, I want to ignore those specific errors, so that the transaction is not aborted. Aborting the transaction is the default behaviour when a request triggers an error.

**The problem**

I thought that using `event.preventDefault()` in the request's `onerror` handler would prevent this from happening. Surprisingly, the event still surfaces in the transaction's error handler! I can see this happening by turning on logging (see the code below).

```
transaction.onerror = function (event) {
    log('IndexedDb.migrateLocalStorage -> transaction -> onerror', event.target.error.name);
};
transaction.oncomplete = function () {
    log('IndexedDb.migrateLocalStorage -> transaction -> oncomplete');
};

for (var key in $W.localStorage) {

    if ($W.localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        value = $W.localStorage.getItem(key);
        request = objectStore.add(addQuotesIfNecessary(value), key);
        request.onerror = function (event) {
            var error = event.target.error;
            log('IndexedDb.migrateLocalStorage -> request -> onerror', error, error.name);

            // do nothing if the same key exists in indexeddb. it is likely newer
            if (error.name === 'ConstraintError') { event.preventDefault(); }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: As this pops out for other searches - sometimes you need to explicitly call transaction.commit(). (unrelated to this Q though)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems the logging output from the code I pasted tricked me into thinking that the transaction was aborted, since the transaction.onerror handler was called. What I did not log, though, was whether transaction.onabort was called ... It turned out that a call to [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) *actually* was enough!

What confused me was that the error propagated up to the transaction error handler. *The transaction was not aborted, though!*. It just bubbled up the event after preventing the default action (aborting). To get rid of the message I also need to call [event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) in order to prevent the event from bubbling up to the transaction's error handler. Note that this is not strictly necessary if you just need the transaction to not be cancelled.

I found the answer by digging around in the W3C docs on [IDBRequst](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#introduction) and IBTransaction.

Answer (score 0):

It is logical that the transaction is in error when something goes wrong inside the transaction. That is way transactions exist, to keep the database consistent.

In your case you should better first check if the key exists. If it does, do nothing in the other case you can insert the data.

An other solution is opening a transaction for every object you want to save....

Comment: That is too simplified. For the case of a WebSQL one can return a boolean from the error handler for the individual statement, which indicates whether the error should be ignored or not. That is what I do if the value already exists - ignore the error, since it is probably newer when migrating data from another backend.

Comment: Found the answer in the W3C docs. There is a performant way of handling this, as I hoped :)

Comment: I'm interested in the problem, but don't yet follow. Can you update your question @oligofren with a restatement of what you've found to be true (perhaps in bullet points)? If you've found event crazyness I wouldn't be entirely surprised.

Comment: @buley I have reworded both the question and the answer to make it more concise and to the point. Hope that helps.